# Filter a list of address objects by a list of string postcodes

Tags: c#, list, winforms, linq, pivot-grid

I have a list of address objects which is used as a data source on a pivot grid. What I have to do is be able to filter the list down based on a list of postcodes.

So, lets say I have 100 address objects in the list (Simple object with Address1, Address2 and PostCode properties).

```
List<Address> addresses = _pivotGrid.DataSource;
```

I have a second list of strings which contain abbreviated postcodes - EG. ML4 3GH is abbreviated to ML4, EH1 3QH is abbreviated to EH1 and so on.

```
List<string> postCodes
```

I want the original list to filter down so it only shows those postcodes that begin with ML4 and EH1 and so on.

Can this be done via Linq?

Comment: `addresses.Where(a => postCodes.Any(p => a.Postcode.StartsWith(p))`?

Comment: Thanks for that - it does not recognize .StartsWith after a.PostCode - but it looks close

Comment: Then it's not a string.

Comment: Hi CodeCaster - I ended up having to do it in a loop. I can't see any other way around it at the moment - but thanks for your assistance